# Spring Integration - Poller fires too often

Tags: java, spring-integration, spring-amqp

I have following code:

```
@Bean
  public IntegrationFlow aggregatingFlow(
      AmqpInboundChannelAdapter aggregatorInboundAdapter,
      PollableChannel aggregatingChannel,
      AmqpOutboundEndpointEnhanced amqpOutboundEndpoint,
      PollSkipAdvice pollSkipAdvice) {
    return IntegrationFlows.from(aggregatorInboundAdapter)
        .wireTap(wtChannel())
        .channel(aggregatingChannel)
        .handle(
            amqpOutboundEndpoint,
            e ->
                e.poller(
                        Pollers.fixedDelay(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS, 1)
                            .maxMessagesPerPoll(DEFAULT_MESSAGES_PER_POLL)
                            .advice(pollSkipAdvice))
                    .id("pollingConsumer"))
        .get();
  }
```

where this `pollSkipAdvice` is defined as

```
@Bean
  public PollSkipAdvice pollSkipAdvice() {
    return new PollSkipAdvice(
        new PollSkipStrategy() {
          int currentPoll = 1;

          @Override
          public synchronized boolean skipPoll() {
            int hitRate = 0; //just not to add to the code; its dynamic
            if (currentPoll >= hitRate) {
              System.out.println(MessageFormat.format("{0} : Hit poll number {1} for message number of {2} | {3}",
                  DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm:ss. SSS")
                      .withZone(ZoneOffset.UTC)
                      .format(Instant.now()),
                  currentPoll,
                  currentMessagesInQueue, Thread.currentThread().getName()));
              currentPoll = 1;
              return false;
            }
            currentPoll++;
            return true;
          }
        });
  }
```

The problem that I facing is that Poller is invoked more than once per second. This is the log that I get when testing my code:

```
21:41:47. 652 : Hit poll number 1 for message number of 0 | pool-3-thread-1
21:41:47. 654 : Hit poll number 1 for message number of 0 | pool-3-thread-1
EventChange(id=190)
21:41:47. 656 : Hit poll number 1 for message number of 0 | pool-3-thread-1
EventChange(id=191)
21:41:47. 658 : Hit poll number 1 for message number of 0 | pool-3-thread-1
21:41:47. 660 : Hit poll number 1 for message number of 0 | pool-3-thread-1
EventChange(id=192)
21:41:47. 662 : Hit poll number 1 for message number of 0 | pool-3-thread-1
EventChange(id=193)
21:41:47. 665 : Hit poll number 1 for message number of 0 | pool-3-thread-1
EventChange(id=194)
21:41:47. 667 : Hit poll number 1 for message number of 0 | pool-3-thread-1
EventChange(id=195)
21:41:47. 669 : Hit poll number 1 for message number of 0 | pool-3-thread-1
21:41:47. 671 : Hit poll number 1 for message number of 0 | pool-3-thread-1
EventChange(id=196)
EventChange(id=197)
EventChange(id=198)
EventChange(id=199)
21:41:48. 653 : Hit poll number 1 for message number of 0 | pool-3-thread-1
21:41:49. 656 : Hit poll number 1 for message number of 0 | pool-3-thread-1
21:41:50. 659 : Hit poll number 1 for message number of 0 | pool-3-thread-1
21:41:51. 661 : Hit poll number 1 for message number of 0 | pool-3-thread-1
21:41:52. 662 : Hit poll number 1 for message number of 0 | pool-3-thread-1
```

So seems that whenever I receive something from AMQP, this Poller will trigger many times. You can see that in logs as `21:41:47. 652` to `21:41:47. 671` triggered 10 times in period of 1 second. On the other hand, as soon as it is over - it works as it should (once per second).

When I try to print stack trace for these 2 occasions when it is only few millis of distance I get this:

```
20:32:56. 406 : Hit poll number 2 for message number of 0 | pool-3-thread-1

java.lang.Thread.getStackTrace(Thread.java:1559)
com.a.configuration.component.EventAggregatorConfig$1.skipPoll(EventAggregatorConfig.java:313)
org.springframework.integration.scheduling.PollSkipAdvice.invoke(PollSkipAdvice.java:51)
org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212)
com.sun.proxy.$Proxy136.call(Unknown Source)
org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint.pollForMessage(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:328)
org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint.lambda$null$1(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:275)
org.springframework.integration.util.ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.lambda$execute$0(ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.java:57)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

20:32:56. 408 : Hit poll number 1 for message number of 0 | pool-3-thread-1

java.lang.Thread.getStackTrace(Thread.java:1559)
com.a.configuration.component.EventAggregatorConfig$1.skipPoll(EventAggregatorConfig.java:313)
org.springframework.integration.scheduling.PollSkipAdvice.invoke(PollSkipAdvice.java:51)
org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212)
com.sun.proxy.$Proxy136.call(Unknown Source)
org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint.pollForMessage(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:328)
org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint.lambda$null$1(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:275)
org.springframework.integration.util.ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.lambda$execute$0(ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.java:57)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Did I configure it in a wrong way? I tried to define separate taskScheduler, but it seems it is not using that one at all.

**UPDATE**

Possibly after a bit of analysis is it possible that it is due to this part in spring `AbstractPollingEndpoint` class:

```
while (this.initialized && (this.maxMessagesPerPoll <= 0 || count < this.maxMessagesPerPoll)) {
                        if (pollForMessage() == null) {
                            break;
                        }
                        count++;
                    }
```

so basically even if I say poll every 1 second, and take 10 messages if there; but do nothing if there are no messages - it will keep try polling if it finds nothing?

**UPDATE2**

Yes, it seems that `skipPoll` advice is called for every message poll and not once for `maxMessagesPerPoll`.

Comment: I see your point in the observation, but what is the question, please ? Just to confirm if that behavior correct or not? Or you have a request to satisfy your logic? Sorry for nit-picking but I’d like to know that we are on the same page.

Comment: @ArtemBilan Just wanted to confirm that this is the case. I guess I assumed that `X per poll` is atomic and that skipPoll should be applicable to all of `X per poll` and not only single message. Not sure if this one is written in the documentation anywhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what is the question. The logic is definitely whatever we would expect from this advice:

```
private Runnable createPoller() {
    return () ->
            this.taskExecutor.execute(() -> {
                int count = 0;
                while (this.initialized && (this.maxMessagesPerPoll <= 0 || count < this.maxMessagesPerPoll)) {
                    if (this.maxMessagesPerPoll == 0) {
                        logger.info("Polling disabled while 'maxMessagesPerPoll == 0'");
                        break;
                    }
                    if (pollForMessage() == null) {
                        break;
                    }
                    count++;
                }
            });
}
```

So, if `pollForMessage()` returns `null` we just break from that `while()` loop and exit from the current polling cycle. That `null` happens from the `PollSkipAdvice` when its `PollSkipStrategy` returns `false`.

You probably just misinterpret polling cycle and really poll. The first one is indeed the moment when trigger hits the time and its `maxMessagesPerPoll`. The real `poll` is indeed about a single `pollForMessage` call. You might need to revise the logic of your custom strategy to meet the existing requirements for such an advice to apply.